# HTML <video> placeholder is black on ipad. Can we change it?

Tags: html, ios, ipad, video, mobile-safari

I must place a `<video>` element in a web page. When accessed from the ipad, the page displays a black placeholder until the visitor hits the play button.

Is it possible to make it white, like one would normally do "background-color: white" in css?

edit: A 'hack' to work this around: Cover the video with an opaque `.shield` layer and have a `.play` button to start the vid.

```
        $('#intro_video .play').selectable({

            start: function(){

                $('#intro_video .play').fadeOut();
                $('#vid').get(0).play();

                setTimeout(function(){

                    // See HACK03
                    $('#intro_video .shield').fadeOut('slow');
                }, 200);
            }       
        });
```

Can be nice to wrap inside a browser check to only affect mobile Safari:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) { ... }
```

Thanks,

Comment: You could put an element over the top that has an image of a play button, and script it to disappear on touch. Kind of a crappy hack though.

Comment: Aha, it's funny... that's what I did but felt bad about this hack... so I came here for a "clean" solution ;-) Thanks though, and yes, it works fine that way... :p

Comment: If it works fine, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put an element over the top that has an image of a play button, and script it to disappear on touch. Not so elegant maybe, but it works.

Comment: The hack works fine, I'll validate it as the answer if no "by the book" solution comes up ;-) Cheers Jezen